# Linked list mystery

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to implement linked Lists.
I therefore have this first class, called List, which represents one element

```
 package list;

/**
 * Linked list with int values.
 * 
 * The empty list is represented by a null reference.
 */
public class List {
    public int value;
    public List next;

    /**
     * Creates a new list
     * 
     * @param value value of the head of the list
     * @param next reference to rest of the list; may be null
     */
    public List(int value, List next) 
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }   
}
```

and the linked list class itself which contains the following method

```
public static int size(List list)
    {
        if(list==null) return 0;
        else return size(list.next)+1;
    }
```

so far everything works. But if I try

```
public static int size(List list)
    {
        if(list.next==null) return 1;
        else return size(list.next)+1;
    }
```

i get a NullPointerException...
I have no Idea why this shouldn't work since list.next should a one point be a reference to the null pointer and end the recursion.
Therefore size(null.next) should never be called.

I apologise for the bad english and am grateful for any help

Comment: You're passing `list.next` to `size(..)` but `size(..)` checks for `list.next`. What are the possible values of `list`?

Comment: I don't really get the question of the comment, but the values of list are either null (List list = null) or this (the list itself)

Comment: So if `list == null` how does `list.next` behave?

Comment: Well that would be the exception. But it should never go that far

Comment: "But it should never go that far" - why not? It is the very first thing your method does: `if(list.next==null) return 1;`. As the comment says - "The empty list is represented by a null reference" - so how does your method deal with an empty list?

Comment: You were right. I forgot that it was possible to call the method on "uninitialised" lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original `size` method handles `null` argument fine.

The second version does not. 

The second version would only give `NPE` if you call `List.size(null)`, for all non-null inputs, it should behave absolutely similarly.

Therefore, just add `if (list == null) return 0;` to your second version.

I really suggest that you declare `size()` a as member method:

```
public int size() {
    return next == null ? 1 : next.size() + 1;
}
```

so you can call : `new List(1, null).size();`

Comment: I know but I don't know where the error is :)

Comment: Well, normally you should not get this, could you give the test input for your `NPE` ?

Comment: Oh that's it! It is actually possible to check the size of uninitialised lists and therefore null.next can be called.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you call `List.size(null)`. In the first version you checl for `list==null`, in the second you don't.

Comment: let's say I have three elements 2->1->null. At 1 the 1.next should give the null pointer and therefore list.size(null) should never be called?

Comment: You gave the example in your own answer. Note the capital `L` to denote the call of the static method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was inspired by a previous comment.

It is actually possible to do this

```
List list = null;
LinkedList.size(list);
```

and therefore if the list is uninitialised `null.next` can be called.
In other words: my list has to have at least two elements (firstelement and null)!

Comment: This code won't work according to sample in the question. You should supply parameter to your `size` method. And yes, it is very confusing usage of your `static` size method, therefore I suggest that you make it member method instead.